# jQuery click both event.target and additional selector

Tags: jquery, selector

Trying to have jQuery access both the event.target and another element on click but receive the error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLButtonElement],#element2
```

Selector code:

```
$(event.target+",#element2").closest("div").removeClass("alert-info").addClass("alert-success");
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong appreciated.

Comment: Please include a [mre] to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.target` isn't a selector string, it's an element.  You can wrap any element in a jQuery object:

```
$(event.target)
```

So you could perform your logic on both the element and the selector:

```
$(event.target).closest("div").removeClass("alert-info").addClass("alert-success");
$("#element2").closest("div").removeClass("alert-info").addClass("alert-success");
```

Or, two reduce a little repetition, you can use [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) to combine jQuery objects into a set of objects:

```
$(event.target).add("#element2").closest("div").removeClass("alert-info").addClass("alert-success");
```

Comment: Three, move your code to a jquery extension `$.fn.alertSuccess = function(...`, then `$(event.target).alertSuccess();$("#element2").alertSuccess();`  - optionally combine with option 2 above.   See https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/